# Como faço para através de um botão no componente "Menu.jsx", chame um Dialog dentro de "Cadastro.jsx"

Tags: react, material-ui

Fala pessoal,

Montei uma pagina que tem um menu (dentro do arquivo "Menu.jsx"), nesse menu tem um botão, que quero fazer abrir um "dialog", tipo um pop-up para cadastrar notas. Esse dialog tem um arquivo próprio "Cadastro.jsx"

Menu.jsx

```
...
export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Button variant="contained"
            style={{ marginRight: 50 }}
            **onClick={() => ???????}**
          >Cadastrar Notas</Button>
          
          <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.title}>
            Calculadora Darf IR Trader
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Ajuda</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cadastro.jsx

```
export default function FormDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Cadastro de Notas</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

A solução fácil que vejo sem olhar o resto do código é que você externalizar o estado que altera a exibição do Dialog, ou seja, se ambos os componentes que você mostrou estão dentro do componente página `Menu`, você poderia:

1. Colocar o `const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);`, e as funções `handleClickOpen`, `handleClose` no componente pai de ambos, (que deve ser o `Menu`).
2. Passar como *props* a função `handleClickOpen` para o componente `ButtonAppBar`, e utilizar essa no local que você colocou as interrogações (?)
3. Passar como *props* o valor de `open` e `handleClose` para o componente `FormDialog`

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, fiz conforme explicou e não funcionou o "onClick", mas confesso que fiz "as pressas" então pode ter passado alguma coisa que ficou de fora.

Estou com uma abas aqui para ler sobre "useState" e props, vou estudar melhor e ver onde errei. Assim que conseguir posto aqui como eu fiz.

Comment: Estranho, deveria funcionar, notei que nesses exemplos você nao utilizou nenhuma props, e não sei o quanto vc já conhece a sintaxe, mas as props são sempre objetos!
Então deveria ficar +- assim a assinatura das funções:
ButtonAppBar({ handleClickOpen })

Mas a idéia é essa, se componentes irmãos precisam conversar entre si, você deve utilizar o componente pai como "carteiro" nessa comunicação.